# d3 Responsive grouped bar chart with tooltip using json file

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I want to use this [Grouped Bar Chart](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051) however I want get data from JSON and not a CSV file. can any one solve my question.

Comment: Use [d3.json](https://github.com/d3/d3-request/blob/master/README.md#json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with

```
d3.json("file.json", function (error, data) {
        console.log(d3.values(data)); // check data in console
        // loop through JSON data
        data.forEach(function (d) {          
            d.value = +d.value;
        });
```

check out this book, it's free and gives a great intro to D3 charts
[D3-Tips-and-Tricks](https://leanpub.com/D3-Tips-and-Tricks/read)